# Fancybox loading

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to init Fancybox plugin without document.ready() event ? 
In FF, it seems to be success but not in IE

To explain : I try to init all jquery functions at bottom of my page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".overview_picM").fancybox({
                'titleShow': false,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                left: picLLeft,
                'autoScale': false,
                hideOnContentClick: true,
                overlayShow: false
            });
</script>
</body>
```

Without document.ready() or window.load, because they slow down.

This is not conventionnal in jquery using, i know, but i have ActiveX, Java Applet or Iframe and all this elements slow down jquery accessibility by using document.Ready or window.load (...)

I have started to implement jquery scripts by this method, and it's successfull for many of my scripts (jquery).

An idea ?
Best Regards,

Sebastien

**EDIT** : 
See explanation to clarify the needs and solutions, below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Thank to Byron for his patience

To explain and Clarify my need :

In my base page, I would like to use fancybox on an `<img>` element to show this element biggest, before iframe (which is in base page too) be loaded.

This iframe contains java Applet and seems to take many seconds to be load/ready (?) in DOM.

So, I noticed that during iframe loading, i can't use fancybox. 
Maybe, fancybox needs DOM be ready to be used correctly, under IE. 
Under FF, it's not necessary, after many tests.
So, I think for threading conflict in IE.

Initial question was not correctly formulated. Sorry.

So, to resolve this problem, I load iframe src in a setTimeout at bottom of my page :

```
        setTimeout('initSrcIframes()',0);

        function initSrcIframes() {
            $("iframe#iframeViewer3D").attr("src", "myUrl.aspx");        

        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

By this way, I can use fancybox plugin as soon as possible in my base page and not after iframe be loaded. I think by setTimeout method, i start new thread (in base page) to load iframe src without penalizing many javascripts features.

I hope this answer clarify my need and will help some people :)

Sébastien

Answer (score 0):

I think that as long as you put the init code AFTER the element on which you would like to apply it (in your case it's something with "overview_picM" class), this should be working.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter when you call the init as long as you do it after the DOM element has loaded.

Comment: I tried but in Ie, fancybox doesn't matter if all elements are not loaded (iframe,...). If I click on "overview_picM" to show fancybox, before iframe is loaded, IE returns some errors : "loading is null or not object" (...)